# Serialized multidimensional stored in MySQLi does not print past first array

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

Confusing title, the basics are that I'm saving a fully sorted and ordered multidimensional array from a script and into MySQL. I then, on another page, pull it from the database and unserialize it, and then proceed to print it out with this,

```
$s = "SELECT * FROM gator_historical_data WHERE channelid = '{$chanid}'";
$r = $link->query($s);

$comboarray = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    $comboarray[] = unserialize($row['dataarray']);
}

foreach ($comboarray as $item) {
    $desc = $item['content']['description'];
    $title = $item['content']['title'];
    $datetime = $item['datetime'];
    // ... ^^^ problems getting array data
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't take the full array from MySQL, only the first entry and thus only prints the first 'array'. So where the returned value from dataarray looks like this (var_dump): http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Z0jy55sM the data stored into the unserialized $comboarray only looks like this (var_dump): http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Ycwwa924

TL;DR: Pulling a serialized multidimensional array from a database, unserializing and it loses all arrays after the first one.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Have you looked at the raw data in the DB to make sure it's stored correctly? Have you considered using JSON instead of `serialize()`?

Comment: Are you sure the table column is big enough to hold the whole array?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking `mysqli_num_rows()` to see how many rows the query returned? there's no way this code would simply skip all but the first entry. while() fetch loops don't "skip" - they just keep doing whatever it is they have to until the while condition returns false. that means if you only get the first entry, you're only getting ONE entry back from the query in the first place

Comment: You don't do any error checking. `unserialize` returns `FALSE` in case it fails and emits an notice (which normally tells what failed). Also double check the column has the right type and size for serialized strings in the database. And what @MarcB wrote.

Comment: @Barmar yes, the first pastebin link shows the returned data from the database which is the full stored data.

Comment: @TecBrat I'll try JSON now, and Marc, the query should only return ONE row, the whole array is stored within one field on said row. It should pull it all from one field and parse it accordingly.

Comment: If the query only returns one row, why do you process it with a `while` loop?

Comment: Force of habbit, I'll change that while I try JSON.

Comment: It looks like you concatenated the results of multiple `serialize()` calls, and stored that in the DB, expecting `unserialize` to return them all as an array. That won't work. You need to combine them all into an array, serialize that whole thing, and store it.

Comment: the same thing is true if you use `json_encode`. You can't append the strings, you have to combine the array and then encode the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you've got is a serialized string plus something more at the end that is also a serialized string again and again:

```
a:3:{s:6:"source";s:25:"World news | The Guardian";s:8:"datetime ...
... story01.htm";}}a:3:{s:6:"source";s:16:"BBC News - World";
                  ^^^
```

This format is not supported by PHP `unserialize`, it will only unserialize the first chunk and drop everything at the end.

Instead create *one* array, serialize it and store that result into the database.

Alternatively you can try to recover for the moment by un-chunking the string, however in case the paste was done right, there are more issues. But on the other hand the paste obvious isn't the done fully correct.

Comment: Bingo! This is now my returned and unserialized data: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=gFjfjpJg But the issue now is that it  doesn't loop any results out at all. See here: http://avx.wc.lt/channel.php?id=world-news

Comment: @AviateX14 Look at the beginning: `array(1) { [0]=> array(295)`. You have everything wrapped in an extra level of array. Get rid of that.

Comment: You sir's are saints.